# How to link button with website in android studio using kotlin

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, kotlin

I want to link button in my application with a website as when user click on this button the website open in browser or in application ,, I using kotlin not java ,,
How can i make it ? :) i try to use this code :

```
bu1.setOnClickListener({
var gourl= Intent(this,Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/"))
startActivity(gourl)
})


 bu1.setOnClickListener({
var gourl= Intent(this,Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/"))
startActivity(gourl)
})

 bu1.setOnClickListener({
var gourl= Intent(this,Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/"))
startActivity(gourl)
})
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do like this:

```
    val url = "http://www.example.com"
    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
    i.data = Uri.parse(url)
    startActivity(i)
```

Or like this:

```
    val i = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.example.com"))
    startActivity(i)
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, it will be very helpful!!!